# How to retrieve active flow via sfdx without creating new flow file

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow, sfdx-plugin

I am trying to retrieve the active version (version 18) of a flow using the following sfdx command :

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Flow:CreateProPM-18
```

According to the documentation :
For Metadata API or SFDX,if the package.xml file is set to API version 44.0 or later. For the latest version of each flow, the file name doesn't include a version number. For example, change myflow-3.flow to myflow.flow.

But for my case (api version 52.0), It is creating a new flow file :

[image]

My sfdx-project.sjon is well set to api greater than 44.0 :
[image]

What am I missing here ? Does anyone is having same issue as me ?

Comment: Is there any newer inactive version of the flow? The version number is skipped in the file name only if you are downloading the newest version (which is not necessarily the latest one).

Comment: Did you try `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Flow:CreateProPM`?

Comment: I am specifying the version here because The latest version is not the active one. If I do not specify the version , it will only download the latest one even if it is not the active one. Finally what I need is to be able to download the active version. The only way here is to specify the version in the name. Normally according to documentation it should not create a file with the version in the name but it is exactly creating what it should not. Thus I may be missing a config here or something else

Answer (score -2):

have you installed this Salesforce Package.xml Generator in VsCode?

if you installed this one you can easily retrieve what you want.

Comment: I'm not really sure how this answers the question. OP is not using a `package.xml` file, and can already retrieve the flow (just not without the version number). [Edit] your question to add details about why this would work (and the steps someone would need to take to make it work)